# Triggering DynamicData cache update using Reactive Subject

Tags: c#, system.reactive, dynamic-data

As a caveat I'm a novice with Rx (2 weeks) and have been experimenting with using Rx, RxUI and Roland Pheasant's [DynamicData](https://github.com/RolandPheasant/DynamicData).

I have a service that initially loads data from local persistence and then, upon some user (or system) instruction will contact the server (TriggerServer in the example) to get additional or replacement data.  The solution I've come up with uses a Subject and I've come across many a site discussing the pros/cons of using them.  Although I understand the basics of hot/cold it's all based on reading rather than real world.

So, using the below as a simplified version, is this 'right' way of going about this problem or is there something I haven't properly understood somewhere?

NB: I'm not sure how important it is, but the actual code is taken from a Xamarin.Forms app, that uses RxUI, the user input being a ReactiveCommand.

Example:

```
using DynamicData;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reactive;
using System.Reactive.Disposables;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class MyService : IDisposable
{

    private CompositeDisposable _cleanup;
    private Subject<Unit> _serverSubject = new Subject<Unit>();

    public MyService()
    {

        var data = Initialise().Publish();
        AllData = data.AsObservableCache();


        _cleanup = new CompositeDisposable(AllData, data.Connect());
    }

    public IObservableCache<MyData, Guid> AllData { get; }

    public void TriggerServer()
    {
        // This is what I'm not sure about...
        _serverSubject.OnNext(Unit.Default);
    }

    private IObservable<IChangeSet<MyData, Guid>> Initialise()
    {
        return ObservableChangeSet.Create<MyData, Guid>(async cache =>
        {
            // inital load - is this okay?
            cache.AddOrUpdate(await LoadLocalData());


            // is this a valid way of doing this?
            var sync = _serverSubject.Select(_ => GetDataFromServer())
                .Subscribe(async task =>
                {
                    var data = await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
                    cache.AddOrUpdate(data);
                });

            return new CompositeDisposable(sync);
        }, d=> d.Id);
    }

    private IObservable<MyData> LoadLocalData()
    {
        return Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)).Select(_ => new MyData("localdata"));
    }

    private async Task<MyData> GetDataFromServer()
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000).ConfigureAwait(true);
        return new MyData("serverdata");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _cleanup?.Dispose();
    }
}

public class MyData
{
    public MyData(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public Guid Id { get; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And a simple Console app to run:

```
public static class TestProgram
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var service = new MyService();

        service.AllData.Connect()
            .Bind(out var myData)
            .Subscribe(_=> Console.WriteLine("data in"), ()=> Console.WriteLine("COMPLETE"));

        while (Continue())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine($"Triggering Server Call, current data is: {string.Join(", ", myData.Select(x=> x.Value))}");
            service.TriggerServer();
        }
    }

    private static bool Continue()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to call server, x to exit");
        var key = Console.ReadKey();
        return key.Key != ConsoleKey.X;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks very good for first try with Rx

I would suggest few changes:

1) Remove the `Initialize()` call from the constructor and make it a public method - helps a lot with unit tests and now you can `await` it if you need to

```
 public static void Main()
    {
        var service = new MyService();
        service.Initialize();
```

2) Add `Throttle` to you trigger - this fixes parallel calls to the server returning the same results

3) Don't do anything that can throw in `Subscribe`, use `Do` instead:

```
var sync = _serverSubject
                .Throttle(Timespan.FromSeconds(0.5), RxApp.TaskPoolScheduler) // you can pass a scheduler via arguments, or use TestScheduler in unit tests to make time pass faster
                .Do(async _ =>
                {
                    var data = await GetDataFromServer().ConfigureAwait(false); // I just think this is more readable, your way was also correct
                    cache.AddOrUpdate(data);
                })
               // .Retry(); // or anything alese to handle failures
                .Subscribe();
```

Comment: Thank you for the pointers, there's tons to pick up on :)  What's your opinion on the Subject usage?
I have figured out another way which was to expose an IObservable<Unit> property that when it's changed the sync part is hooked up.
This means that the SourceCache has to be managed manually

Comment: To be honest when I use SourceCache, I just treat it as a normal ObservableCollection - `new SourceCache` etc. Subject is a no go when you expose it as public member. Your use is OK

Answer (score 0):

I'm putting what I've come to as my solution just in case there's others that find this while they're wandering the internets.

I ended up removing the Subjects all together and chaining together several SourceCache, so when one changed it pushed into the other and so on.  I've removed some code for brevity:

```
public class MyService : IDisposable
{
    private SourceCache<MyData, Guid> _localCache = new SourceCache<MyData, Guid>(x=> x.Id);
    private SourceCache<MyData, Guid> _serverCache = new SourceCache<MyData, Guid>(x=> x.Id);

    public MyService()
    {
        var localdata = _localCache.Connect();
        var serverdata = _serverCache.Connect();
        var alldata = localdata.Merge(serverdata);

        AllData = alldata.AsObservableCache();
    }

    public IObservableCache<MyData, Guid> AllData { get; }

    public IObservable<Unit> TriggerLocal()
    {
        return LoadLocalAsync().ToObservable();
    }

    public IObservable<Unit> TriggerServer()
    {
        return LoadServerAsync().ToObservable();
    }
}
```

EDIT: I've changed this again to remove any chaining of caches - I just manage the one cache internally.  Lesson is not to post too early.